# Mysql delete 5th element of a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
 ID Friend
John    Rita
John    Jack
Jack    Rita
Rita    John
John    Peter
John    Owen
John    Eric
John    Louis
```

I want to write a query where I delete all `ID`'s after the 5th element. In other words I want to keep for each `ID` maximum 5 `friends`.

I have tried with a `group by` or something like that, but I don't now exactly how I have to do the delete.

The result must be:

```
  ID    Friend
John    Rita
John    Jack
Jack    Rita
Rita    John
John    Peter
John    Owen
John    Eric
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. [The reason is that RDBMS's do not do not guarantee the order of entries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql).

If you need to be **certain** of the rows you are deleting, then you will need to know the order. I would recommend starting by adding an auto incrementing primary key column. From that, you will at least be certain of the order of entries. Eg:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Note: This will only guarantee the order of ***future*** entries, ***not*** previously inserted entries.